# Sizing and placing buttons with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to place buttons on a worksheet on opening the workbook.  I have accomplished that much, but cannot seem to get the buttons to be placed in a reliable fashion.  By that I mean I am trying to place the buttons on the top and right sides of the active worksheet defined as "Landing."  However, when I try to set the parameters the spaces do not seem to be consistent.  My code is:

```
Dim Landing As Worksheet
Dim ImportBankTransButton As Button
Dim FinancialStatementsButton As Button
Dim LogInButton As Button
Dim NewBankAcctButton As Button
Dim ChangeBankAcctButton As Button
Dim NewExpenseButton As Button
Dim ChangeExpenseButton As Button
Dim ChangeLogInButton As Button
Dim PullUpLogInButton As Button
Dim PastStatementsButton As Button
Dim AcctMaintButton As Button

Dim trial As Button


Set Landing = Activeworkbook.Sheets("Welcome")
ChDir ("temp")

Landing.Buttons.Delete  'deletes all current buttons to reset the page
    'Adding buttons back to page
        'Buttons.add(left parameter, top parameter, width parameter, height parameter)
Landing.Buttons.Add(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - 640, ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Height - 425, 120, 45).Select
Set ImportBankTransButton = Selection
With ImportBankTransButton
    .Text = "Import Banking" & vbNewLine & "Transactions"
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 12
    .OnAction = "ImportBankingTransactions"
End With

Landing.Buttons.Add(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - 455, ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Height - 425, 120, 45).Select
Set FinancialStatementsButton = Selection
With FinancialStatementsButton
    .Text = "Generate Financial" & vbNewLine & "Statements"
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 12
    .OnAction = "UnderConstruction"
End With

Landing.Buttons.Add(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - 290, ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Height - 425, 120, 45).Select
Set LogInButton = Selection
With LogInButton
    .Text = "New Log-In" & vbNewLine & "Information"
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 12
    .OnAction = "UnderConstruction"
End With

Landing.Buttons.Add(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - 125, 25, 80, 35).Select
Set NewBankAcctButton = Selection
With NewBankAcctButton
    .Text = "Add New Bank" & vbNewLine & "Account"
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 10
    .OnAction = "CreateNewAccountPreForm"
End With

Landing.Buttons.Add(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - 125, 70, 80, 35).Select
Set ChangeBankAcctButton = Selection
With ChangeBankAcctButton
    .Text = "Change Bank" & vbNewLine & "Account Info"
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 10
    .OnAction = "UnderConstruction"
End With

Landing.Buttons.Add(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - 125, 115, 80, 35).Select
Set NewExpenseButton = Selection
With NewExpenseButton
    .Text = "Create New Expense" & vbNewLine & "(Sub-Account)"
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 10
    .OnAction = "UnderConstruction"
End With

Landing.Buttons.Add(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - 125, 160, 80, 35).Select
Set ChangeExpenseButton = Selection
With ChangeExpenseButton
    .Text = "Change Expense" & vbNewLine & "(Sub-Account)"
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 10
    .OnAction = "UnderConstruction"
End With

Landing.Buttons.Add(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - 125, 205, 80, 35).Select
Set ChangeLogInButton = Selection
With ChangeLogInButton
    .Text = "Change Existing" & vbNewLine & "Log-In Info"
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 10
    .OnAction = "UnderConstruction"
End With

Landing.Buttons.Add(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - 125, 250, 80, 35).Select
Set PullUpLogInButton = Selection
With PullUpLogInButton
    .Text = "Go To Log-In" & vbNewLine & "Information"
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 10
    .OnAction = "ShowLogIn"
End With

Landing.Buttons.Add(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - 125, 295, 80, 35).Select
Set PastStatementsButton = Selection
With PastStatementsButton
    .Text = "Open Past" & vbNewLine & "Statements"
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 10
    .OnAction = "UnderConstruction"
End With

Landing.Buttons.Add(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - 125, 340, 80, 35).Select
Set AcctMaintButton = Selection
With AcctMaintButton
    .Text = "MyLife File" & vbNewLine & "Maintenance"
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 10
    .OnAction = "AccountMaintenance"
End With
```

Everything shows up, the buttons are functional.  Buttons 4 - 11 show up with a small (~1.4cm) space between the right edge of the button and the right edge of the window, which is equal to the "45" difference between the width of the screen less 125 (activewindow.visiblerange.width - 125) and the width of the button (80).  However, when I try to set the next button to be inside (left of the button just placed) by another 45 (buttons 1 - 3 above) it places a much larger gap (~2.5cm)?  I would think that using the adding 45 and the width of the new button to the left edge of the rightmost button would yield the same gap (activewindow.visible range.width - (125 + 45 + 120)). What am I missing are the units not consistent?

Additionally, being new to VBA, any comments/suggestions to make the code more efficient are welcome!

Thank you all.

EDIT: Thank you to everyone weighing-in!  In response to many of the comments, I am trying to make this sheet work and look the same depending on the size of the screen, thus using dynamic placement.  It will trigger on "open" and on "resize."  Additionally, there isn't any code except activate the page and exit sub.

Comment: Why do that dynamically not using the designer?

Comment: Hi A.S.H, thanks for the quick reply...I can't say however, that I understand what you mean.  I'd love to learn more about it if it's a better way to handle it, could you point me to some references/material or give me an example?

Comment: my point is,  you can much better control the locations and sizes of your shapes and controls with the designer, and since you're creating them *"on opening the workbook"*, it looks difficult to justify the dynamic creation.

Comment: I'm using the dynamic creation because it will resize based on the screen used, as it also is triggered by resizing events.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Probably, after all t is your project and you know the reason. I was just trying to understand the motivation and to point out that the designer should be preferred unless dynamic creation is justified. That doesn't mean that I was judging your approach as wrong however :)

Comment: I appreciate the help, honestly.  This is all new to me, I've only been learning it in my spare time for about 3 months now.  I just can't seem to understand why a 45 (whatever unit it is) space would look different in different spots?

Comment: You can set the buttons to size automatically based on the cell size. 
So I am not sure why you are adding these buttons dynamically, unless there is a reason that I am aware of

Comment: @JMB I see your point. Indeed I've already experienced trouble with these issues in dynamic creation/placement of controls. I used to deal with it with trial and error.

Comment: Is this really the minimum code needed to demonstrate the problem? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I believe so, but I guess that may be part of the problem?  There isn't really any other code in this particular sub (which just "sets" up the page on open and resize).  The buttons do work and are there, just seem to obey odd standards for units.

Comment: umm, wait, I have some doubts. Could you specify which button exactly is misplaced with regard to your expectation, and why?

Comment: @ A.S.H - Sure, buttons 1 - 3 (Import..., Financial..., LogIn...) are not placed appropriately.  I've added (what I believe to be a 45 (not sure of the units used in VBA)) space between the edge of the window and the edge of the buttons 4 - 11, and then a 45 space between the left edge of buttons 4 - 11 and the right edge of button 3 (LogIn), but the space is MUCH larger.

Comment: In my calculations, your numbers set the distance between button4/right and widow/right-edge to 45, distance between button3/right-edge and button4/left-edge to also 45. That's right. But the anomaly is in the way you define the right-edge of the window. You may be considering that the edge is before the scrollbar... while it is defined in windows as the "extreme" right edge, beyond the scrollbar. That might explain it.

Comment: Thank you for checking the calculations, I feared that was what I was doing wrong (which would be terribly embarrassing).  I did measure past the scroll bar however, the gap is significantly larger between the buttons than the edge and button 4.  It's odd.

Comment: The definition of the window's right edge is a bit fuzzy. That said, check the spacing between your first 3 butons, the distances there are not the same.

Comment: Finally, you can shorten your code and avoid using `select`, For example, just this:               `With Landing.Buttons.Add(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Width - 640, ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Height - 425, 120, 45)
             .Text = "Import Banking" & vbNewLine & "Transactions"  etc`